# Run script on remote server via PHP

Tags: php, shell

I have a game server company and on my control panel I currently have a page where a user can click a button and it installs a world on their game server. How this is done is via a script on the node which extracts the world onto their game server.

I have a few nodes and the panel is hosted on my web server. How would I do it so when they click the button on the website, it not only posts the value of the form to the script but also runs the script?

If you need to know, the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$SERVERID

if [ "$WORLD" = "testworld" ]; then
     cd "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server$SERVERID"
     unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/maps/testworld.zip"
fi

exit 0
```

The variable $WORLD is what needs to be sent to the script as a POST from the form on the control panel.

The variable $SERVERID is defined at the top of the script and needs to also be sent from the form on the control panel. The control panel has already defined this variable, it just needs to be sent to the script as part of the form.

I am quite sure how to echo the $SERVERID variable on the line:

```
cd "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server$SERVERID"
```

So help with that is also appreciated.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: well im confused, if you could sum up the question in one sentence it would be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the script on your server as an Shell script, which accepts $WORLD and $SERVERID as command line arguments. After that run that script from PHP using `exec` or `system` command.

Now, your Shell script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

id=$SERVERID

if [ "$1" = "testworld" ]; then
 cd "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server${2}"
 unzip -nu "$JAR_DIR/maps/testworld.zip"
fi

exit 0
```

Save it as, let say `script.sh`. Now, call it from PHP.

```
exec("script.sh " . $WORLD . " " . $SERVERID);
```

I hope I got your question correctly, and It helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry, the question was a little confusing. The help from the shell script section was very helpful! How does the {1} and {2} work?What do they do? In reference to the php, the php section is on a web server, the shell script is on another server so php needs to call the script from remote server.

Comment: $1, $2 ... are command line arguments given to the script. For example in `script.sh arg1 arg2 .. argN` $1 will contain "arg1", $2 will contain "arg2" and so on.

Comment: In case you are confused about curly brackets in ${1}. In ${1}, {} is used to separate variable name from other text, for Example in "${1}Hello" ${1} is variable ad Hello is other text. It is not clear if we just write "$1Hello".

Comment: ahh, I see! Thanks.  In reference to the php, the php section is on a web server, the shell script is on another server so php needs to call the script from remote server, how do I do that?

Comment: You are telling that you don't have a web server running on the server where the shell script needs to be run, right? In this case you can try `ssh` via PHP. I don't know much about this option, or setup a small web server just to call shell scripts. In either case you will have to setup a server on the machine you want to use for shell script.

Comment: I do have a web server on it, it just isn't the server where the control panel is the location. The PHP end of things is on a different server than the SHELL script side of things.

Comment: Then it is quite easy. Create a PHP script with exec command on the SHELL Script server. Then call this script from your actual web server. You can do this by using php-curl of simply file_get_contents. Take care of security in case you don't want your SHELL server to be publicly available. Sorry for the late reply.